# Snap web framework and OSX Path

Tags: macos, haskell, yesod, haskell-snap-framework

preface: new to OSX development.

cabal install snap --this works fine.

When I type snap into the terminal nothing happens. How do I export my snap path to my $PATH in OSX?

same thing happens with happstack and yesod.... those are both installed as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply do (in the terminal):

```bsh
export PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH"
```

To make it permanent, add that line to the hidden `.profile` file in your home directory and re-login. You can edit `~/.profile` using `open ~/.profile`. This can also be done with this line in the terminal:

```bsh
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
```

Comment: Hey, I ran what you gave me and it wrote the proper directory into my profile, but snap still gives "command not found" my profile looks like this: export PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH". In fact my .cabal directory doesn't have a bin folder...