# Where is snap web framework (Haskell) on Mac OSX installed

Tags: macos, haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I am trying to install snap on my MAC OSX, the `cabal install snap snap-templates` command worked, but after that when I try `snap init`  I get the error that snap command does not exist.

I have already checked the question:  [Snap web framework and OSX Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748148/snap-web-framework-and-osx-path) and it does not help me.

I checked the Haskell/bin and .cabal/bin path and cannot see any snap file there. So where is the file installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to my snap installed at the location: /users/admin/library/haskell/bin

I am a new user of Mac and was confused as I was trying to find snap in /library/haskell/bin, where it was not present. On using the find command: `find / -name "*snap*"` I was able to find the correct path. At least am able to do now use snap, by referring it using the complete path. Still trying to figure out the correct file to put the path in though.

Answer (score 1):

It puts binaries in `~/.cabal/bin`.  As [mentioned here](http://snapframework.com/faq#why-cant-i-install-snap), make sure you have that at the beginning of your PATH.

Comment: I have already tried the options given in the link, also have created a .bash_profile file with the path in my etc directory, but it still does not work. As I mentioned I cannot see the binaries in the ~/.cabal/bin path.